# Как можно поправить в ie11 grid?

Tags: css

Привет! Сделал блок на grid, но в ie11 не работает.
Есть ли возможность обойти баг?  Префиксы галп добавляет.
Как я понимаю не работает grid-row в ie .

[Пример][1]

[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/drtvader/7khh5htf/3/ .

```css
.b-activity-content__grid {
  padding: 0;
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-align-content: space-around;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: distribute;
  align-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.b-activity-item {
  -ms-grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.b-activity-item--row-1 {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.b-activity-item--row-2 {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.b-activity-item--row-3 {
  grid-row: 3;
}

.b-activity-item--column-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.b-activity-item--column-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.b-activity-item--column-3 {
  grid-column: 3;
}

.b-activity-item--big {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.b-activity-item__link {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.b-activity-item__image-item {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  font-family: "object-fit: cover";
  width: 100%;
}

.b-activity-item__text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2.26px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="b-activity-content__grid">
  <li class="b-activity-item b-activity-item--big">
    <a class="b-activity-item__link" href="javascript:void(0);" alt=""><img class="b-activity-item__image-item js-image-wrapper" src="http://www.factroom.ru/facts/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/122-620x420.jpg" alt="ЗАБЕГ" title=""><span class="b-activity-item__text">
                  <p>ЗАБЕГ</p></span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="b-activity-item b-activity-item--column-2">
    <a class="b-activity-item__link" href="javascript:void(0);" alt=""><img class="b-activity-item__image-item js-image-wrapper" src="http://www.factroom.ru/facts/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/122-620x420.jpg" alt="ЛЕКТОРИЙ" title=""><span class="b-activity-item__text">
                  <p>ЛЕКТОРИЙ</p></span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="b-activity-item b-activity-item--column-3">
    <a class="b-activity-item__link" href="javascript:void(0);" alt=""><img class="b-activity-item__image-item js-image-wrapper" src="http://www.factroom.ru/facts/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/122-620x420.jpg" alt="Мастер-классы от фитнес-блогеров" title=""><span class="b-activity-item__text">
                  <p>Мастер-классы от фитнес-блогеров</p></span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="b-activity-item b-activity-item--column-2 b-activity-item--row-2">
    <a class="b-activity-item__link" href="javascript:void(0);" alt=""><img class="b-activity-item__image-item js-image-wrapper" src="http://www.factroom.ru/facts/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/122-620x420.jpg" alt="ЙОГА-марафон" title=""><span class="b-activity-item__text">
                  <p>ЙОГА-марафон</p></span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="b-activity-item b-activity-item--column-3 b-activity-item--row-2">
    <a class="b-activity-item__link" href="javascript:void(0);" alt=""><img class="b-activity-item__image-item js-image-wrapper" src="http://www.factroom.ru/facts/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/122-620x420.jpg" alt="партнерские МАСТЕР-классы " title=""><span class="b-activity-item__text">
                  <p>партнерские МАСТЕР-классы </p></span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="b-activity-item b-activity-item--column-1 b-activity-item--row-3">
    <a class="b-activity-item__link" href="javascript:void(0);" alt=""><img class="b-activity-item__image-item js-image-wrapper" src="http://www.factroom.ru/facts/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/122-620x420.jpg" alt="женский фитнес от студий" title=""><span class="b-activity-item__text">
                  <p>женский фитнес от студий</p></span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="b-activity-item b-activity-item--column-2 b-activity-item--row-3">
    <a class="b-activity-item__link" href="javascript:void(0);" alt=""><img class="b-activity-item__image-item js-image-wrapper" src="http://www.factroom.ru/facts/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/122-620x420.jpg" alt="культурная программа" title=""><span class="b-activity-item__text">
                  <p>культурная программа</p></span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="b-activity-item b-activity-item--column-3 b-activity-item--row-3">
    <a class="b-activity-item__link" href="javascript:void(0);" alt=""><img class="b-activity-item__image-item js-image-wrapper" src="http://www.factroom.ru/facts/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/122-620x420.jpg" alt="Здоровое питание" title=""><span class="b-activity-item__text">
                  <p>Здоровое питание</p></span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Судя по тому, что говорит caniuse в ie11 поддерживается старая версия спецификации https://caniuse.com/#search=grid-row, возможно, в документации есть как это обойти https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-grid-layout-20110407/

Comment: есть еще статья про гриды в IE10, IE11 and Edge https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/